# Pointer arithmetic of unspecified type with known size

Tags: c, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
void * ptr = NULL; // array of unspecified 13-byte type

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%i ", ((char (*) [13]) ptr) + i);
}

putchar('\n');
```

Output:

```
0 13 26 39 52 65 78 91 104 117
```

So this works (at least on GCC) but how can I declare a variable of type `(char (*) [13]` so I wouldn't have to do that cast everytime I want to perform pointer arithmetic on that pointer?

And is this behavior even portable?

Comment: First of all, your program has an undefined behavior as pointer arithmetics on an invalid pointer is UB. Second, the size of you "object" is `13` and is an array of `char` of size 13, i.e `char x[13];`

Comment: `"%i"` is for `int`, not pointers.  Better to use `printf("%p ", (void*) some_object_pointer_expression);`

Comment: I am aware of that, it's just for readability, with `%p` the output would be something like this: `(nil) 0xd 0x1a 0x27 0x34 0x41 0x4e 0x5b 0x68 0x75` And of course I would never do that in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pointer arithmetic of unspecified type with known size
>
> And is this behavior even portable?

Strictly: maybe:

Need a deep dive into `C17 6.3.2.3 Pointers`

Something like below relies on the value of `&fred[0]` being able to convert to `ptr` without trouble.  Many implementations will handle this without a problem, yet `ptr` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to `char`.  Had `ptr` been a pointer to `char`, no problem.

I *think* since `ptr` and `fred` both have the same alignment requirement - code is OK.

```
typedef something unspecified_13_byte_type;
assert(sizeof(unspecified_13_byte_type) == 13);

#define N
unspecified_13_byte_type fred[N];

char (*ptr)[13] = (void *) fred;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  // printf("%i ", ((char (*) [13]) ptr) + i);
  printf("%p ", (void *)  (((char (*) [13]) ptr) + i));
}
puts("");
```

---

Deeper:  if `something` is some `struct`, then `ptr` and `&fred[0]` need not be the same encoding or even the same size - even if they well convert to and from each other and equate to each other.  `struct` pointers and `char *` can be more different that usually expected - even if such differences are very uncommon today.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
char s[10][13];
//…
void * ptr = s;
```

The array `s` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[13]`.

Or you could write

```
char s[10][13];
//…
char ( *tmp )[13] = s;
void * ptr = tmp;
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the pointer arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 13 };
    char s[][N] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };
    const size_t M = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );

    void * ptr = s; 

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", ( ( char ( * )[N] )ptr )[i] );
        // or
        // printf( "%s ", *( ( char ( * )[N] )ptr + i ) );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A B C D E F G H I J
```

Comment: That's definitely not what I'm trying to do. I have no intention of ever dereferencing the pointer. I just need to return the right address (ptr + i * size_of_type) I just want to know if I could cast it to `char (*) [size_of_type]` to take advantage of the pointer arithmetic syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Salt And what is the problem? The demonstrative program shows the pointer arithmetic. If you do not want to dereference the pointer then what is the problem?

Comment: @Salt In my answer there is shown how the corresponding array can be declared.

Comment: I'm not trying to declare a new array. I'm trying to declare a pointer that would increment by 13 when I do something like `ptr++`

Comment: Then I must be blind, which line did you show that in?

Comment: @Salt In the demonstrative program there is clear written the casting of the void pointer. And in the beginning of the answer there is also said to what pointer the pointer void corresponds. You should investigate the demonstrative program.

Comment: Okay I apologize for wording my question horribly (and perhaps misunderstanding everything you've said up to this point) but I'm trying to avoid having to cast from a void pointer everytime I want to do pointer arithmetics on that pointer. And to do that I would like to know how to declare a variable of type `char (*) [13]`

Comment: @Salt Just write char ( *ptr )[13].

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? `ptr` wasn't even allocated. Casting it will result in undefined behavior.

You can either do this

```
void * ptr = malloc(10 * 13); // on heap
```

OR this

```
void * ptr = (char [10][13]){}; // on stack (C99)
```

Comment: Casting `NULL` is undefined?

Comment: @Salt The cast in your code is not UB so "Casting it will result in undefined behavior." is off the mark.  The pointer addition in your code is UB.  Jared Pyzynski later suggestions are good.